# VBS file communication/execution

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a ftp server that i have written VBS scripts for, now I need an easy way to run them from my website. So i want to open my website, enter the username, password, users name and click submit, it must then run the VBS and insert the data and the VBS will then create the user on the FTP.

What is the best way to do this? should I load the VBS stuff into a application with webservice listener and build and execute it and then my site must communicate via the webservice, or should i rather build a local asp page and host it which when posted too runs the vbs file and gives it the data. Please explain how you would go about coding it if you leave a response :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<%
    Dim oWShell
    Set oWShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strCommand = "cmd.exe /c cscript C:\AbsolutePath\To\Your\VBSFile.vbs"
    oWShell.Run strCommand, 1, true
    Set oWShell = Nothing
%>
```

WShell and WShell.Run requires elevated access permissions on the web server. Make sure that the authenticated user (or IUsr) has those permissions.